# What does #ifdef WIN32DLL_EXPORTS mean?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I've created a DLL a file, and in the header file I see :

```
#ifdef WIN32DLL_EXPORTS
```

I don't understand what does it mean and where/how we can set up `WIN32DLL_EXPORTS`.

if I use:

```
#ifdef WIN32DLL_EXPORTS
    #define WIN32DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define WIN32DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

WIN32DLL_API int testSum(void);
```

`testSum` is considered as `__declspec(dllimport)`. So I think my project is not set to `WIN32DLL_EXPORTS`? How can I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either:

- define `WIN32DLL_EXPORTS` in the project's `Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor` definitions.
- if you use a precompiled header (e.g. stdafx.h) then you can also define `WIN32DLL_EXPORTS`
   there with a `#define` statement.

Comment: -1 This does not even attempt to answer the question. And should definately not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

There is a comment block immediately above the line you quoted. Read it.

```
// The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which make exporting 
// from a DLL simpler. All files within this DLL are compiled with the WIN32DLL_EXPORTS
// symbol defined on the command line. this symbol should not be defined on any project
// that uses this DLL. This way any other project whose source files include this file see 
// WIN32DLL_API functions as being imported from a DLL, wheras this DLL sees symbols
// defined with this macro as being exported.
#ifdef WIN32DLL_EXPORTS
#define WIN32DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define WIN32DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```